# Что нужно ввести для вывода самой минимальной даты в python?

Tags: python, django, дата

Что нужно написать вместо конкретного числа в скобках?

```
startdate = self.request.GET.get("startdate")
            if not startdate:
                startdate = date(2021, 1, 1 )
```

Comment: Просто `date.min` без скобок

Comment: ошибка: значение даты вне диапазона

Comment: Значит спрашивайте у того, кто вам выдал эту ошибку, что это за диапазон такой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку ответ принадлежит уважаемому  **andreymal**, здесь лишь воспроизвожу его в форме понятной ТС. И подтверждающей правильность ответа. На авторство, естетственно, не претендую.

```
from datetime import date
startdate = date.min
print(startdate)
```

Результат:

```
0001-01-01
```